# INVALID_FETCH_SESSION_EPOCH errors with confluent HDFS sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have been trying to get the confluent HDFS sink connector to work, without success. I have a distributed kafka connect cluster (3 nodes) with version 5.2.2 of the confluent platform, talking to a 5-node kafka cluster running kafka 2.3.0.

I have an event generator writing events to a topic with 3 partitions and replication factor 1. I see the events appearing in HDFS, and everything looks correct.

However, for topics with a different number of partitions, or a different replication factor, nothing is written to HDFS. Instead I get errors that look like this:

```
Node 121 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=378162138, epoch=7242): INVALID_FETCH_SESSION_EPOCH. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:381)
```

These events appear in the kafka connect logs and it looks like one of these appears for each attempt to commit.

For a topic with 3 partitions, and replication factor 1, everything works.

For a topic with 3 partitions, and replication factor 2, nothing is written to HDFS.

For a topic with 50 partitions, and replication factor 1, nothing is written.

In fact, if I increase either the replication factor or the number of partitions, nothing is written to HDFS.

I can't seem to find the right configuration to make this work. What settings should I be paying attention to?

Comment: FWIW, The error is related to consumer settings (request timeouts and poll sizes), not topic configuration... Maybe your flush size is too high in the connector config? I assume there's data in those other topics?

Comment: @cricket_007 - thanks for the suggestion - i reduced my flush size by 90% and i was able to see files written for a topic with 50 partitions, rep factor 2.  my actual production use case is 360 partitions, rep factor 2, and i can't get it to work for that either.

Comment: What did you set for `tasks.max` for either case?

Comment: i set tasks.max = 1.

Comment: This means you only have one consumer thread trying to read tens to hundreds of partitions, and it cannot keep-up. Ideally, you set this to the number of partitions for all consumed topics.

Comment: i think that fixed it!  thanks very much for your help!

Comment: when a consumer gets this error, has it lost the messages, or does it get the messages on a subsequent read?